# Apex Validation Trigger issue

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Some quick background of what I'm trying to do..

The following is my Apex Trigger. It is a validation Trigger on `Sampling_c` which will validate that `Country_c` is a Valid country using `Validation_country_c`. When it validates `Country_c` it will look into `State_province_c` and will then validate that it is actually a state So .. If `Country_c = US and State_province_c = CA` then we are okay. But `IF Country_c = US and State_province_c = ZZ221(whatever)` it should fail. Now these condition checks only triggers when `Override_c = 'Yes'`.

`Description__c` holds my `State_Province__c` validation info

So this is where I am at so far.
I was able to return all of my System.debugs so the conditions are right besides this one which has my uncovered line of code.

```
if(validRegions.get(countryKey) != null && validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey) != null) {
 Validation_Region__c vr= validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey);
            System.debug('This is VR'+vr); //This doesn't return
```

I believe it is because regionKey is not being filled properly here.

```
For(Validation_Region__c objR : [Select Id,Country_Key__c,Description__c,Name FROM Validation_Region__c]){
String countryKey = objR.Country_Key__c;
System.debug('System Debug!!!!' + objR.Country_Key__c);

Map<String, Validation_Region__c> regionMap = validRegions.get(countryKey);
// Maybe rework to use Map.containsKey rather than null check. Would be cleaner.

if(regionMap == null) {
    System.debug('Inside regionMap == Null condition');
    regionMap = new Map<String, Validation_Region__c>();
    validRegions.put(countryKey, regionMap);
    System.debug('This is Broken' +validRegions);
}
string regionKey = objR.Description__c; 
regionMap.put( regionKey,objR);
}
```

With the help of a few members here I have written my test class which I will post below, along with my full code.  Thanks for all the help.. I know I've asked for a lot of it over the last couple days.

Test Class --

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class OverrideTest{

static testmethod void addressOverride(){

    Sampling__c s = new Sampling__c();

    Validation_Region__c region = new Validation_Region__c();
    region.Name = 'US';
    region.Country_Key__c = region.Name; 
    insert region;

s.Quantity_of_Samples__c = 2;
s.Override__c = 'Yes';
s.Country__c = 'US';
s.State_Province__c = 'California';
insert S;
}
}
```

Trigger--

```
trigger OverrideTrigger on Sampling__c (before insert) {

// Top level map is keyed by Country. Inner Map is keyed by Region   
Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>> validRegions = new Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>>();
// ...


For(Validation_Region__c objR : [Select Id,Country_Key__c,Description__c,Name FROM   Validation_Region__c]){
String countryKey = objR.Country_Key__c;
System.debug('System Debug!!!!' + objR.Country_Key__c);

Map<String, Validation_Region__c> regionMap = validRegions.get(countryKey);
// Maybe rework to use Map.containsKey rather than null check. Would be cleaner.

if(regionMap == null) {
    System.debug('Inside regionMap == Null condition');
    regionMap = new Map<String, Validation_Region__c>();
    validRegions.put(countryKey, regionMap);
    System.debug('This is Broken' +validRegions);
}
string regionKey = objR.Description__c; 
regionMap.put( regionKey,objR);
}


For( Sampling__c s : Trigger.new){
If((s.Country__c != null) && (S.Override__c == 'Yes')){
    String countryKey = s.Country__c;
    String regionKey = s.State_Province__c;

    System.debug('This is the countryKey'+countryKey);
    System.debug('This is the regionKey' +regionKey);

        if(validRegions.get(countryKey) != null &&  validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey) != null) {
            // The Region belongs to the country
            System.debug('This is the validRegions'+validRegions );
            Validation_Region__c vr= validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey);
            System.debug('22345 This is VR'+vr);
        }else{
                System.debug('Breaking');
             break;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should add a couple more debug statements to your trigger code; Debug out the values of `validRegions.get(countryKey)` and `validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey)` before the `if` block and then you'll know which of your maps is missing expected data.

Comment: Can you show us how do you feed your map 'validRegions' ? What are the results your are getting ?

Comment: validRegions is created by 
    Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>>   validRegions = new Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>>();  
and then in my validRegions.put(countryKey,regionMap);  But I believe the logic is skewed.  Right now my System.debug for it spits out US which is my input on my test class.

Comment: Hi Mark, good call on that I will go ahead and look into that deeper now.
14:54:18.111 (6111359000)|USER_DEBUG|[31]|DEBUG|This is the countryKey{null=Validation_Region__c:{Name=US, Id=a1SL0000000kAEbMAM, Country_Key__c=US}}
14:54:18.111 (6111444000)
|USER_DEBUG|[32]|DEBUG|This is the regionKeynull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks much for the help, I relized that I wasn't actually passing anything back with my Test class..  Here is what I updated with my test class.  Thanks for the responses

```
Validation_Region__c region = new Validation_Region__c();
    region.Country_Key__c = 'US';
    region.Description__c = 'California';
    region.Country_Key__c = region.Country_Key__c;     
    insert region;
```

Comment: Little update to this.  Just because this works doesn't mean its right, so what I mean by that is I'm "artificially" populating Validation_Region__c which I shouldn't be because I already have that information in that object so I need to figure out why that is happening.